# c# Identity LogOff and print message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

My user logoff correctly after a period of inactivity defined in my `ExpireTimeSpan` of my `CookieAuthentication`, i would like to print a message in my login redirection when the logoff happen, is there a way to do that?

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/signin"),
            CookieName = ".Cookies",
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom redirect with something like this:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // [...]
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // [...]
                OnApplyRedirect = ApplyRedirect
            }
        });

        app.Use<ClaimsLogger>();
    }

    private static void ApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context)
    {
        // custom redirect logic
        var uri = context.RedirectUri;
        context.Response.Redirect(uri);
    }
```